# Is it safe to purge resolvconf if you handle /etc/resolv.conf via puppet?

Tags: resolv.conf, purge, puppet, resolvconf

We have multiple servers running 12.04 LTS and 10.04 LTS with static network settings. Is it safe to purge the package `resolvconf` if you handle `/etc/resolv.conf` via puppet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is advisable *not* to purge or remove the resolvconf package even if resolv.conf is managed by something other than resolvconf. The reason is that the mere presence of resolvconf suppresses various other programs' default behavior of futzing directly with /etc/resolv.conf. So you probably want to keep the resolvconf package installed in order to suppress that futzing.

Note that the resolvconf program never touches /etc/resolv.conf directly: it writes its dynamic resolv.conf file at /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf and /etc/resolv.conf is normally a symbolic link to the latter. So if puppet puts a file at /etc/resolv.conf instead of the symlink then resolvconf won't overwrite it.